# How to implement Syntax Highlighting and Auto-Complete feature in C#.NET GUI Application?

Tags: c#, autocomplete, syntax-highlighting

I am a new C# student programmer. I want to make a editor like application which will highlight codes (syntax highlighting) and have auto complete feature for functions variables etc... I don't have any idea to do that. Can you please provide me some tutorial links or some tips about that? Can I implement these features in a "Rich Text Box"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The text editor component from the open source SharpDevelop IDE can be freely downloaded and used. This supports all your requirements. See http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/TextEditorControl.aspx for an explanation on how this can be done.

Comment: Source code is not working in Visual Studio 2010. Why? Can you please explain?

Comment: @Chanchal1987 - You have two make two changes after converting the project. Firstly, remove `using NUnit.Framework;` from Program.cs. Secondly, you must set the TextEditor project as the startup project (right click, Set as StartUp Project). The warnings can be safely ignored.

Answer (score 3):

Off the top of my head there are three open-source text editor controls you can download:

- [Scintilla.NET](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fscintillanet.codeplex.com%2F&ei=v-fLTNjEGceOjAf1-53WBw&usg=AFQjCNH0ALiVA8sNsHGa47CX1IQLS5VEZA&sig2=jKF6hhdNFgETLEcg6Eb5wg)
- [AvalonEdit](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/AvalonEdit.ashx) (the #Develop editor)
- [FireballFX](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dotnetfireball/)

I'm sure there are others but these are pretty tried and tested.